# How to use toggle to shorten my code?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**html is:**

```
<div class="top-buffer myclass glyphicon glyphicon-grain"></div>
```

**jQuery is :**

```
$(".myclass").on("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).removeClass("glyphicon-grain").addClass("glyphicon-qrcode");
});
$(".myclass").on("mouseout", function(){
    $(this).removeClass("glyphicon-qrcode").addClass("glyphicon-grain");
});
```

The above works fine. How can **I use toggle and make the code shorter?**

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this snippet.

```js
$("body").on("mouseover mouseout", 'div.myclass', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-grain glyphicon-qrcode");
});
```

```css
.glyphicon-grain
{
  color: green;
}
.glyphicon-qrcode
{
  color: blue;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-buffer myclass glyphicon glyphicon-grain">Div with toggle class</div>
```

Comment: Thank you .. Never knew about including multiple events in same query like `"mouseover mouseout"`

Comment: @Somename: You can use multiple events in a same query by using space only.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".myclass").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-grain glyphicon-qrcode");
});
```